# How to OrderBy in Many to Many Relationship in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I have two tables `products` and `categories`. Products can have many categories and categories can have many products.(The relationship between these two tables is `many-to-many`)

To map the associations between these two tables I have created another new table `product_categories` which stores `product_id` and `category_id`.

Following is my annotations used in entities to join these three tables.

**Product Entity**

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="products")
 */
private $categories;
```

**Category Entity**

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="categories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_categories",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $products;
```

Now the problem is, I want to order the records in `product_categories` into a certain order. So I added a new column called `serial_number` to `product_categories` table.

The result what I am trying to achieve is when I am retrieving categories to a product using `$product->getCategories()` the resulting category array should be ordered by the `serial_number`.

I have tried the following annotations.

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="categories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_categories",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 * @OrderBy({"product_categories.serial_number"="DESC"})
 */
private $products;
```

But this results in an annotation syntax error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@OrderBy" in property ProductBundle\Entity\Product::$products was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in /var/www/sonicwall.local/app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php on line 54

When I use `@ORM\OrderBy({"product_categories.serial_number"="DESC"})`, I do not get a syntax error but results are not getting ordered either.

My question is, is there a way to achieve this using annotations without me having to create new Entities and Repositories for `product_categories` table?

Comment: I think it should be `@ORM\OrderBy`? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks @Bossman! I updated the question with the errors.

Comment: Try `@ORM\OrderBy({"serial_number" = "DESC"})` or `@ORM\OrderBy({"serialNumber" = "DESC"})`

Comment: Nope..still not getting ordered according to the serial number!

Comment: Can you show us the serial number in your entity ?

Comment: Serial number is just an integer. (1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [@ORM\OrderBy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/tutorials/ordered-associations.html):

> ```
> @OrderBy acts as an implicit ORDER BY clause for the given fields, that is appended to all the explicitly given ORDER BY items.
>
> All collections of the ordered type are always retrieved in an ordered fashion.
>
> To keep the database impact low, these implicit ORDER BY items are only added to a DQL Query if the collection is fetch joined in the DQL
> ```
>
> query.

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="categories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_categories",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"serialNumber"="DESC"})
 */
private $products;
```

You tried to do something similar, but with `product_categories.serial_number`. You do not need `product_categories` because the order by will try to sort every member of the collection with its own field. So just writing `serialNumber` will sort by each product serial number.

However, I just saw that you already tried something similar in comments so makes sure to use the attribute name as your field: `serialNumber`, `serial`, ... as it appear with `$serialNumber`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still doesn't order!(its like it just completely ignores the OrderBy) 
Also ``product_categories`` is the relationship table so I do not have Entity class created for that table so I do not have ``$serialNumber`` variable.